# Switch from Saxon HE to Saxon PE in WSO2 BPS

Tags: wso2, saxon, wso2-esb

I need to switch WSO2 Business process server to use Saxon PE, rather than embedded Saxon HE as I'm using Saxon extensions for XSLTs.

I tried to remove the initial plugin from /repository/components/plugins/saxon.he_9.4.0.wso2v1.jar and put both Saxon PE jar and licence file into /lib and /lib/endrosed as was suggested [here](http://heshans.blogspot.com/2011/07/changing-underlying-xslt-processor-of.html)

That didn't help much as I'm still getting:

```
TID: [0] [BPS] [2013-01-09 11:08:08,551]  INFO {org.apache.ode.bpel.runtime.ASSIGN} -  Assignment Fault: {http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsbpel/2.0/process/executable}subLanguageExecutionFault,lineNo=96,faultExplanation={http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsbpel/2.0/process/executable}subLanguageExecutionFault: org.apache.ode.utils.xsl.XslTransformException: XSL Transformation failed! {org.apache.ode.bpel.runtime.ASSIGN}
TID: [0] [BPS] [2013-01-09 11:08:08,551]  INFO {org.apache.ode.bpel.runtime.ASSIGN} -  Assignment Fault: {http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsbpel/2.0/process/executable}subLanguageExecutionFault,lineNo=96,faultExplanation={http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsbpel/2.0/process/executable}subLanguageExecutionFault: org.apache.ode.utils.xsl.XslTransformException: XSL Transformation failed! {org.apache.ode.bpel.runtime.ASSIGN}
```

The transformation fails however the same request gets transformed as expected and without any errors in unit test, so I presume BPS doesn't aware that it should use PE.

Also if an element that needs to be transformed using the extension is not arriving in the request - transformation works well.

Could anyone advise on this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This solution](http://nandikajayawardana.blogspot.com/2012/12/how-to-replace-saxonhe940wso2v1jar-in.html) worked perfectly for me (just few easy steps to follow).